# Embedded Kafka Refresh Messages Between Tests

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I'm using Spring Kafka with the the `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation to start the Embedded kafka instance.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I've configured my application to connect to it:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

I am successfully sending messages and consuming messages.

My problem is that the messages are retained somewhere and may appear in proceeding test runs. And the logs are printing these:

```
Successfully joined group with generation 117
```

The high generation number indicates that Kafka is retaining information between test reruns that i do not want.

**How do I completely clean up Embedded Kafka and start fresh?**

EDIT:

The issue I had was I was using Spring Profiles incorrectly. I had a custom annotation annotation with my embedded Kafka configuration. The problem was I was setting `@ActiveProfiles("kafka")` in the compound  annotation, and also setting `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` in the actual test class. I've updated the compound annotation to this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
// @ActiveProfiles("kafka") REMOVED
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}")
@EmbeddedKafka(/* config properties */)
public @interface CustomEmbeddedKafka{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `@DirtiesContext` to clean an application context in between tests. Together with that the embedded Kafka broker is going to be destroyed as well.

If the problem is between one test class methods, then you need to rethink the logic over there do not interfere with the same topics in different methods.

You also can consider to use `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`, but this is going to be some kind of performance degradation, since an application context together with an embedded Kafka is going to be recreated before every test method.

**UPDATE**

Try this suggestion instead of `application.properties` modification:

```
static {
    System.setProperty(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.BROKER_LIST_PROPERTY,
            "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
}
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/#kafka-testing-embeddedkafka-annotation

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` does not work. The Embedded Kafka is retained even outside of the `applicationContext` for some reason. It's not just between tests in a test group. Messages are picked up like a day after the previous test.

Comment: Then it looks like you connect to the real Kafka outside of your project...

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Looks like this was the case. I was just using Spring Profiles incorrectly.